# SQL execute scalar returning NULL

Tags: c#, sql, executescalar

```
queryShelf = "SELECT * FROM shelftable WHERE ShelfId= @ShelfId";

//Create Mysql Command
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(queryShelf, connection);

cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@ShelfId", MySqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = MainWindow.shelfIds[i];

//ExecuteScalar will return one value
int Count = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar() + "");
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? What is the first column of the first row that query returns?

Comment: Don't use * in the query. You need to return a value, not an "array" of values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ExecuteScalar` is used to  return a **single value**, you are selecting complete records. So normally you use `ExecuteReader` and use `Read` to get all records.

But actually you can use `ExecuteScalar` with `SELECT *`. What happens is that the **first column of the first row** in the result set is returned, or a **null** reference  if the result set is empty.

Since you get `NULL` it seems that the filter doesn't return a record.

Since you want a count you could change your query to:

```
queryShelf = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM shelftable WHERE ShelfId= @ShelfId";
// ...
int Count = (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Now you never get `null` but the count of records, 0 if no record exists with this `ShelfId`.